# aspose license path for azure function deployment

Tags: aspose.words

I am deploying my asp.net application which has aspose.words in azure cloud. The application starts with azure function. I am facing issue in placing the aspose license. I have kept the aspose license in bin folder which contains aspose.words.dll. But I get invoked member does not exist error:

```
Aspose.Words.License license=new Aspose.Words.License();
license.SetLicense("Aspose.Words.lic"); //Error invoked member does not exist
```

Can someone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case the best way is to include the license file as an embedded resource in your project. Please follow the [link](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Licensing#Licensing-IncludingtheLicenseFileasanEmbeddedResource) to learn how to do this. Hope this helps.

Disclosure: I work at Aspose.Words team.